# Apache2 redirect https://www to https://non-www

Tags: apache, redirect, apache2, no-www

I want to redirect `https://www.mydom.com` to `http://mydom.com`

I have an `mydom.conf` into `apache2/sites-available/`

`mydom.conf:`

```
#HTTP(www/non-www) -> HTTPS(non-www)
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName mydom.com
   ServerAlias www.mydom.com

   Redirect permanent / https://mydom.com/

</VirtualHost>

#ACTIVATE HTTPS AND REVERSE PROXY -> test-1.0.0
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

   SSLEngine On

   SSLCertificateFile /opt/ssl/new/mydom_com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/ssl/new/mydom_com.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/ssl/new/mydom_com.ca-bundle

   BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
   SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

   ServerName mydom.com
   ServerAlias www.mydom.com

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/test-1.0.0/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/test-1.0.0/

</VirtualHost>
```

With this `mydom.conf` It works partial.

Domains `http://mydom.com` and `http://www.mydom.com` are redirected to `https://mydom.com` . This is good.

My problem is at `https://www.mydom.com` it is not redirected to `https://mydom.com`, but show the content from `https://mydom.com`

How I can redirect `https://www.mydom.com` to `https://mydom.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple vhosts block

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

   SSLEngine On

   SSLCertificateFile /opt/ssl/new/mydom_com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/ssl/new/mydom_com.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/ssl/new/mydom_com.ca-bundle

   BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
   SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

   ServerName mydom.com

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/test-1.0.0/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/test-1.0.0/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

   SSLEngine On

   SSLCertificateFile /opt/ssl/new/mydom_com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/ssl/new/mydom_com.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/ssl/new/mydom_com.ca-bundle

   BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
   SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

   ServerName www.mydom.com

   Redirect permanent / https://mydom.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The only thing you need make sure is that certificate is valid for both `example.com` and `www.example.com`, so that you don't get https exception before the redirect.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your idea but only with `ServerName` and `Redirect` without `SSL`. I don't understand why don't work without `SSL`. After all it's a redirect.

Comment: The reason is when the browser accesses `https//www.domain.com`, it makes an SSL connection. So you need to have an SSL block to allow the first connection to happen. Then only the redirection can be sent

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a .htaccess file using vi command in the public_html folder or document root of your website. Add the code below in your .htacess file.

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydom.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydom.com/$1 [R=301]`

If you have an existing .htaccess file in the public_html folder, try to make a backup using the command below:

$ mv .htaccess .htaccess.bak

or

$ cp .htaccess .htaccess.bak

Hope this helps.

Comment: This can't be achieved by using VirtualHost?